# Does having my keyword phrase in every title of my page good?

Tags: google, keywords, seo, title

Does having my keyword phrase in every title or in `<strong></strong>` tag, help my website to achieve a good rating or rise in my keyword in google?

For example....

If I have "how does the" keyword phrase, which has !% global competition and over 11,000 searches (with phrase search only) and I use this phrase in every of my page title as it is starting phrase...

How will that benefit me?

Comment: You really need to start asking more questions about how you can please your users, and less asking how to please search engines. You're clearly focusing on the wrong stuff and it's going to prevent your website from doing well.

Comment: John, I have always kept priorty in serving the best to my users. However, I am doing this because, there are geniue website out there serving the best. However, they lack strategy in exposing the best they have.  Q:  like eHow.com where they start with "how to" in 80% of their article. Assuming that I want to do same to "how does the" in my articles, like how does the iphone work?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe.

Keywords in the `<title>` is only one of about 200 factors Google claims to use so doing this isn't going to make a difference unless you are targeting phrases that have a lower competition. I wouldn't recommend "stuffing" the keyword into the title unless it makes sense. Otherwise you'll confuse or annoy your users and it may trigger a manual review of your website which can end with your pages being devalued and ranking poorly.

`<strong>` tags have less influence then the title so using it will have very little impact on your page's rankings.

Comment: Thanks John, However, I do understand that it is/maybe one of 200 factors. I don't intend to stuff my keyword. I just want to know, just like eHow.com where they start with "how to" in 80% of their article. Assuming that I want to do same to "how does the".

Comment: Thanks John, I do understand that it is/maybe one of 200 factors. I don't intend to stuff my keywords.I just want to know, just like eHow.com where they start with "how to" in 80% of their article. Assuming that I want to do same to "how does the" in my articles, like how does the iphone work? or how does the android os work? The keyword phrase has less than 1% competition and 11 k global search. I am ready to wait for 6 month or more, where google will start indexing the articles. "if my website justify the keyword phrase", it will be on an increase.  ain't I right? or Maybe wrong?

Comment: Every page on SE network contains SE name in title. Blogspot puts blog name to the title of each article. It's quite a common practice, so the OPs question is very legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate titles annoy Google, so you need distinct tiles that are useful to your customer for each page. Proper headings within the pages and actual page content with external inbound links from trusted sources probably count more for better ratings.